# Jquery hide and show not working on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem with jquery hide/show (or alternatively `display:none / block`) I want to hide Support button, but it always only blinking, when moving mouse over it. Can you help me? Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umeyaspz/) and code samples:

**HTML**

```
<div class="photo">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="voting">
    <span class="vote">Support</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.photo {
    position: relative;
    width: 270px;
    height 230px:
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.something {
    width: 270px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.voting {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(0,0,0,0.17) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(1%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.17)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.17) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.17) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.17) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.17) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 );
    text-align: center;
}

.voting .vote {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 66%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 14px;
    font-family: 'uni_sans_bold_rgdregular', Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

and **JS**

```
$(".photo").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".voting").css("top", "0px");
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".voting").css("top", "");
});

$(".vote").hover(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}, function() {
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: This happens because of the 2nd function where you invoke show, it basically go back and forth between the functions. if you remove the 2nd function then the support disappears. you have a problem with the logic of your code.

Comment: So how can I fix it? :-(

Comment: You can use `:hover` class of CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second function inside `$('vote').hover(function(){...})` and add following line of code `$('.vote').show();` inside your`$(".photo").hover(function(){...})`. (To show it again when you hover the square element)

So your code should look like this -

```
$(".photo").hover(function () {
    $('.vote').show(); /* Shows the .vote button again */
    $(this).find(".voting").css("top", "0px");
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".voting").css("top", "");
});

$(".vote").hover(function () {
   $(this).hide(); /* Hides the .vote button on hover */
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfv2kgs0/1/)**